# Unity 3D how to rotate an object so that its oriented correctly based on the ground plane?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm using an asset called Dreamteck Splines to create a path, what I'm trying to do is make it so when I rotate the spline the game object the pink cube in this case, also rotates so it's oriented correctly on the path whether its upside down or sideways like a roller coaster. For some reason, I can only rotate the path to about 90 degrees before the cube stops rotating to align itself to the path. 
[GIFF](https://media.giphy.com/media/ctNJHGXne9qNwK83QG/giphy.gif)

```
if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.W))
    {
        vehicle.transform.Translate(0, 0, speed * Time.deltaTime);

    }
    if (Physics.Raycast(vehicle.transform.position, Vector3.down, out hit, 100))
    {
        Vector3 surfaceNormal = hit.normal; // Assign the normal of the surface to surfaceNormal
        Vector3 forwardRelativeToSurfaceNormal = Vector3.Cross(vehicle.transform.InverseTransformDirection(vehicle.transform.right), surfaceNormal);
        Quaternion targetRotation = Quaternion.LookRotation(forwardRelativeToSurfaceNormal, surfaceNormal); //check For target Rotation.
        vehicle.transform.rotation = Quaternion.Lerp(vehicle.transform.rotation, targetRotation, Time.deltaTime * 20); //Rotate Character accordingly.

    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found this which does what I was trying to achieve:

```
 void Update()
{
    /*Here we get user input to calculate the speed the ship will get*/
    if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.W))
    {
        /*Increase our current speed only if it is not greater than fwd_max_speed*/
        current_speed += (current_speed >= fwd_max_speed) ? 0f : fwd_accel * Time.deltaTime;
    }
    else
    {
        if (current_speed > 0)
        {
            /*The ship will slow down by itself if we dont accelerate*/
            current_speed -= brake_speed * Time.deltaTime;
        }
        else
        {
            current_speed = 0f;
        }
    }

    /*We get the user input and modifiy the direction the ship will face towards*/
    yaw += turn_speed * Time.deltaTime * Input.GetAxis("Horizontal");
    /*We want to save our current transform.up vector so we can smoothly change it later*/
    prev_up = transform.up;
    /*Now we set all angles to zero except for the Y which corresponds to the Yaw*/
    transform.rotation = Quaternion.Euler(0, yaw, 0);

    RaycastHit hit;
    if (Physics.Raycast(transform.position, -prev_up, out hit))
    {
        Debug.DrawLine(transform.position, hit.point);

        /*Here are the meat and potatoes: first we calculate the new up vector for the ship using lerp so that it is smoothed*/
        Vector3 desired_up = Vector3.Lerp(prev_up, hit.normal, Time.deltaTime * pitch_smooth);
        /*Then we get the angle that we have to rotate in quaternion format*/
        Quaternion tilt = Quaternion.FromToRotation(transform.up, desired_up);
        /*Now we apply it to the ship with the quaternion product property*/
        transform.rotation = tilt * transform.rotation;

        /*Smoothly adjust our height*/
        smooth_y = Mathf.Lerp(smooth_y, hover_height - hit.distance, Time.deltaTime * height_smooth);
        transform.localPosition += prev_up * smooth_y;
    }

    /*Finally we move the ship forward according to the speed we calculated before*/
    transform.position += transform.forward * (current_speed * Time.deltaTime);
}
```